# AWS Cross-account deployment for CloudFormation keeps getting denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-cloudformation

I've been trying to set up a pipeline in CodePipeline which deploys services from one account to another. But I just keep getting this error:

> Cross-account pass role is not allowed (Service: AmazonCloudFormation; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied;

Here I have 2 accounts:

Deployment account: Here I have the CodeCommit repo with the template I want to deploy. This is the source of CodePipeline which is in the same account. From the deployment account I want to deploy a stack into the test account though CloudFormation.

Test account: Here I want to deploy the stack. Here I have a cross-account role which gives CloudFormation the permission to use all services I want to use. This role also has a trust relationship with the deployment account.

So I want the pipeline in the deploy account to deploy a stack in the test account.

Pipeline settings:

- For CodePipeline I've set up a role which has the assume (test account)role statement.
- For CloudFormation I've used the cross-account role which is created in the test account.

When i test the pipeline it keeps getting the error I've stated above.

Anyone has an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS CodePipeline error: Cross-account pass role is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48362572/aws-codepipeline-error-cross-account-pass-role-is-not-allowed)

Comment: The idea is that i have the template etc in the deployment account. This pipeline deploys a stack in the test account. But my set up keep telling me i cant use the pass role. I've been looking at the examples i can find about other similar solutions but these don't seem to answer my use case. Most tell about deploying code or using S3 buckets. I just need to deploy a stack in a different account and can't seem to figure out where i've been using the wrong roles

Comment: Please paste all policy and role documents (hidding sensitive information)